# Unexpected keyword argument 'thread_name_prefix' when subscribing to Google Cloud PubSub emulator

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, pipenv

I am trying to implement a pubsub class using Google Cloud pubsub emulator.
I am doing that on Docker using Python and it is based on Flask.
Everything works perfeclty when I install Google Cloud SDK with a requirement file, however when I try to use `pipenv` I get the error mentionned in the title and I cannot figure out how not to have it.

This is what the raw output looks like:

```
Unexpected error:<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 18, in <module>
    pubsub.init()
  File "/app/pubsub.py", line 85, in init
    subscription = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/client.py", line 139, in subscribe
    subscr = self._policy_class(self, subscription, flow_control)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/policy/thread.py", line 90, in __init__
    self._executor = self._get_executor(executor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/policy/thread.py", line 134, in _get_executor
    **executor_kwargs
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'thread_name_prefix'
```

This is the Dockerfile that creates the base image (which is then used as a base for the app):

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine
RUN set -x && apk add --no-cache build-base && pip install pipenv 
WORKDIR /api
COPY Pipfile ./ 
COPY Pipfile.lock ./ 
RUN set -ex && pipenv install --deploy --system
```

By the way, when I do `RUN pip install google.cloud.pubsub` right after the `pipenv install`, it does work, so it really has something to do with `pipenv`.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Could you also share the contents of Pipfile and Pipfile.lock?

Comment: It might be due to older version of python